# Visual Studio Function Debugging

Tags: c++, logging, windbg, trace

I am working on **VS 2008**. I wish to get the following information for all my methods:

1) Time at call entry

2) Time at call exit and the return value.

GDB allows me to set a break point at each function entry and exit and run a script at the breakpoint and then continue debugging. I am tired of looking for solutions to do something similar on VS. I even thought of writing a script to parse my entire code and write fprintf's at entry and exit but this is very complex. Desperately looking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using windbg, you can also set at each function entry and run a script.
For instance the following command will add a breakpoint on all functions of your module, display the name of the function, the current time, run until the function exit, display the time and continue.

```
bm yourmodule!* "kcL1;.echotime;gu;.echotime;gc"
```

Comment: Can I print the return value. I am compiling a big source code with lots of dll's. Do I give the .exe file here?

Comment: .logopen and .logclose to redirect output to a file.

Comment: return value in $retreg register

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is a function level Time-Based Profiling (TBP). Several tools can help you on this:

- Visual Studio Profiling Tools: which is available with Visual Studio Ultimate and Premium version only. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx
- Intel vTune: It can do lots of things, including function level profiling. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/
- AMD CodeAnalyst: it is a free tool. It can work with Intel CPU as well (with limited function, but enough for your purpose). It can do source code level profiling: http://developer.amd.com/cpu/codeanalyst/codeanalystwindows/pages/default.aspx

I suggest you to try with AMD CodeAnalyst first. If you don't have Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate edition.

Comment: I don't want to profile the code. I have already used the stand alone profiler for VS 2008. I have Professional btw. I want the output to be like the strace output. eg. Timestamp foo -> rv. Does AMD Code Analyst give me this output?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are suing c++. You can define a time trace class which display the timestamps

```
/* define this in a header file */
class ShowTimestamp {
private:
    static int level_;   // nested level for function call tree

private:
    const char *func_;
public:
    ShowTimestamp(const char* f) : func_(f) {
        std::cout << func_ << ":" << (level_++) << ":begin\t" << GetTickCount64() << std::endl;
    }

    ~ShowTimestamp() {
        std::cout << func_ << ":" << (--level_) << ":end\t" << GetTickCount64() << std::endl;
    }
};

#ifndef NO_TRACE_TIMER
  #define TIMESTAMP_TRACER     ShowTimestamp _stt_(__FUNCTION__); 
#elif
  #define TIMESTAMP_TRACER
#endif
```

The level_ should be declared in a CPP file separately.

```
// You need to define the static member in a CPP file         
int ShowTimestamp::level_ = 0;
```

In your code, you can do

```
int Foo(int bar) {
  TIMESTAMP_TRACER 

  // all the other things.
  ......

  return bar;
}
```

If you don't want to trace timer any longer, you can just define NO_TRACE_TIMER

Comment: ShowTimestamp could be refined to add indent for nested function calls.

Comment: +1 for the nested function calls. So looks like there is no other way but to insert statements in every function.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is not suited for this; you would have to use WinDbg.  It has its own scripting language that would allow you to do what you are seeking.  Unfortunately I don't know the first thing about it's scripting language; you will have to read the help file (which is actually more-or-less useful, for once).